# Use class instead of className in react components

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I use next js and mycode like below

```
import styles from "../components/style/dark.module.scss";

export default function ThemeButton() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button id="dark-mode-toggle" className={styles["dark-mode-toggle"]}>
 
      </button>
      <h1 className={styles["title"]}>
       Title
      </h1>
    enter code here
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here I am creating an CSS module and importing it and using like above and it works fine.

But everytime I need to type `className={styles["dark-mode-toggle"]}` instead of just typing `class="dark-mode-toggle"` , I am migrating from plain html code to React and there are 1000's of class like this.

Is there any way to use `class="dark-mode-toggle"` and make styles work ,  without using global styles , I want the styles to be imported only when component is used to make my app lightweight.

Comment: Since it's JSX, it won't work. However in VSCode you can replace all occurances in a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> in VScode and replace all occurrences in the project.